# Kafka Streams Message Consumption order

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The topic contains 10 partitions that have messages generated every 3-to-4 seconds by various IoT devices. The key on the message is LocationId and DeviceId.The value is device related details.

The stream topology is deployed to 4 EC2 instances. The process must determine the latest update value from each of the devices and analyze for criticality.

What I am seeing is that since messages are distributed across multiple partitions, stream consumer sees older messages and they are not in order.

How do I determine the latest message for the specific key?

I am seeing following message behaviour on Kafka Cluster -

```
L1D1 at 1:00 am - critical=false (P1)
L2D2 at 1:00 am - critical=false (P1)
L1D1 at 1:02 am - critical=**true** (P2)
L2D2 at 1:05 am - critical=false (P1)
L1D1 at 1:03 am - critical=false (P2)
L2D2 at 1:03 am - critical=false (P1)
```

Notice that at 1:02 device D1 had a critical alert, but at 1:03 it wasn't. If processing messages by the stream is 1:03, 1:02 (any random order based on the partition)

How do I determine the latest message for specific device efficiently since the order is not guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I determine the latest message for specific device efficiently since the order is not guaranteed?

Kafka guarantees message ordering *within a topic partition*, but not *across multiple topic partitions*. What you need to do is to ensure that messages from the same device are being sent to the same topic *partition*. If you haven't changed Kafka's default settings, you can achieve this by using a device-specific identifier (think: `DeviceId`).

> What I am seeing is that since messages are distributed across multiple partitions, stream consumer sees older messages and they are not in order.

If you use a composite key like `(LocationId, DeviceId)`, then you will not get updates for the same device in order, because the device's messages are distributed across *multiple partitions* because the message key includes also `LocationId`.

> The process must determine the latest update value from each of the devices and analyze for criticality. [...] How do I determine the latest message for specific device efficiently since the order is not guaranteed?

In your case I would change the message key from `(LocationId, DeviceId)` to just `DeviceId`. Let's call this "stream D".

If you still need the original grouping by `(LocationId, DeviceId)`, you can achieve this by subsequently re-grouping (aka re-keying aka re-partitioning) the stream D from `DeviceId` to `(LocationId, DeviceId)` into a new, derived stream LD.

Answer (score 0):

What is your stream processing strategy? KSQL or the SDK?
If you use KSQl you just need to create a stream/table

check:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/create-a-table.html

Comment: Would this table will keep growing in memory?

Comment: No depending on how you group it, it will take only the latest value per group, have a look at some of the KSQL videos. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExEWJVjj-RA

Comment: KSQL requires an additional server. Is this can be achieved some other fashion?

Comment: Then you need to use kafka sdk https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html